# Unable to access WPF Elements from user class

Tags: c#, wpf

Pasted below is my partial C# Code for a WPF Project.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public class sc
        {
            string name, content, stopol, client, bkpset;
            public void getndadd()
            {
            }
        }
        sc obj = new sc();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I have a few textBoxes & Labels created. When the button (button1_Click) is clicked,I'd like to store the values in an object of the class "sc". 
For this I have written a method getndadd(). But I can't seem to get the textbox,labels or any of the WPF Elements as I type.

Any idea why ? I've pasted below what I want & what I actually get.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because different classes of scopes. In order to transfer textbox, you need to approach your class sc (getndadd ()) takes a parameter (eg FrameworkElement) in order to transmit it to a value.

```
public class sc
{
  string name, content, stopol, client, bkpset;
  public void getndadd(FrameworkElement element)
  {
     var elem = element;
     ...
  }
}

 public MainWindow()
 {
    InitializeComponent();
    sc.getndadd(textBox1);
 }
```

Comment: thanks but how to pass all elements at once ? I don't wanna include sc.getndadd(textbox1)...sc.getndadd(textbox5) as 5 different statements for different textboxes or pass too many parameters to the method. anything more efficient  ? btw did u mean different "scopes of classes" in ur answer? uve written "classes of scopes"

Comment: to pass all the elements:
Option 1: Send MainWindow instance (getndadd(MainWindow window)) and get all elements in Window
Option 2: Send a base type (Window) and get logical tree of it.

Answer (score 1):

Your window is an instance of your `MainWindow` class. When you click on button 1, `button1_Click` gets called, which is a member function, so it has access to all properties of that window, including `textBox1`.

Your `sc` class (or rather, instances of it) knows nothing of your window. You could create an `sc` instance without having any windows open, or you could have multiple windows... which textBox should `sc` use in that case?

One solution is to pass a reference to your `MainWindow` instance:

```
public class sc
{
    // (...)

    public void getndadd(MainWindow window)
    {
        // Here, you can access window.textBox1, and any other public properties
    }
}
```

Or you could let `button1_Click` set the various fields of your `sc` instance:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    obj.name = textBox1.Text;
    // and so on...
}
```

However, WPF comes with a so-called 'data binding' system that can automate this. Each WPF element has a DataContext property. You can link element properties to properties in its DataContext, for example:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Description}" />
```

By default, the DataContext of your `MainWindow` is the `MainWindow` instance itself, so in this case, WPF checks if your `MainWindow` class contains a `Description` property. If it does, the label will automatically display the value of that property as its content. This system can work both ways.

If you set the DataContext of your `MainWindow` to a `sc` instance, then you can bind to its properties (note that you'll need to use properties for this to work, not simple fields):

```
<Label Content="{Binding name}" />
<Label Content="{Binding content}" />
<Label Content="{Binding stopol}" />
```

And so on. If you want your view to be updated automatically when you change one of these properties in your code, you'll have to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, and raise a `PropertyChanged` event in the setter of each property, so WPF knows when a property (and which property) got changed.

A final note: some of your names are quite undescriptive - I can't tell what `sc` and `getndadd` stand for or what they're supposed to do. Also, class and method names in C# are CamelCased by convention.